# asp.net passing an instance of a class between pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On page one I would like to create an instance of a class as such:

```
    pOne = New pClass()
    xOne = New xClass(pOne)
```

Then on subsequent pages I would like to be able to use pOne and xOne. Since pOne and xOne are local to page one how can I use them in other pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use Session variable to store that object and use it in another page.

```
//Set the session
Session["p1"]=pOne;
Session["x1"]=xOne;
```

in second page, read the session

```
if(Session["p1"]!=null)
{
   // If object is present in session, Cast that to our class (PClass) type
   PClass objP1=(PClass) Session["p1"];  
   //Now you can use objP1
}
if(Session["x1"]!=null)
{
   XClass objx1=(XClass) Session["x1"];  
   //Now you can use objx1 
}
```

It is a good practice to always do a null check before accessing a variable

**Here is the VB.NET version** ( I hope this works,  I don't have much experience in VB.NET)

```
 // Set the Session
 Session("p1")=pOne
 Sesssion("x1")=xOne
```

In second page read the session,

```
 if Session("p1") IsNot Nothing Then
   Dim objP1 As pClass       
   objP1=CType(Session("p1"),pClass)   
   'Now you can use objP1
 End If

 if Session("x1") IsNot Nothing Then
   Dim objX1 As xClass
   objX1=CType(Session("x1"),xClass)
   'Now you can use objX1
 End If
```

Comment: except you'll want to use VB.net rather than the C# the Shyju used :P

Comment: If you're going to do this, you should **definitely** create entries in your project's resources or settings file and reference those entries when accessing the Session. Nothing is more irritating than tracking down a bug related to a typo.

Comment: Be wary of writing objects to session. The entire object graph has to be serialized, and de- serialized. This may not be a major overhead depending on your object, but I've seen people write large composed objects to session...

Comment: I have been doing this in the session object  - but that makes me a little concerned about performance. Currently, I have a small user base and performance in acceptable but as things grow larger I don't know how well storing class instances in the session object will scale.

Comment: Its not good to store many objects in session. In that case, I would suggest you to pass ids in the querystring and load the object again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `HttpContext.Items`, then you don't have to clean up lingering objects, they will go away unless you reset them:

[Use HttpContext Item Collection to pass objects across pages](http://samgaut.blogspot.com/2011/04/use-httpcontext-item-collection-to-pass.html)